# How to refer to variables when the names are indefinite and must be found by regex first, using Coldfusion?

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I have an html form that collects variables that look like:

```
ent1_label
ent2_label

ent1att1_label
ent1att2_label
ent2att1_label
ent2att2_label

ent1att1val1_label
ent1att1val2_label
...
ent2att2val2_label
```

I don't know in advance how many of ent, att, or val will be coming from the form to the action script. In the input form, I run loops that concatenate the variable names:

```
ent<cfoutput>#i#</cfoutput>att<cfoutput>#j#</cfoutput>val<cfoutput>#k#</cfoutput>_label
(where i, j, and k are the number of ent, att, and val)
```

This works great on the input form, but then I'm lost on how to refer to them in the action script.

I've played around with #form.fieldnames# which has all of the actual variable names.

```
<cfset #formfields# = listToArray(#form.fieldnames#, ",")>
<cfset #formlength# = arraylen(#formfields#)> 
<cfset #entattval_label# = arrayNew(1)>
<cfloop from="1" to="#formlength#" index="i">
<cfif REfind("ENT[0-9]*ATT[0-9]*VAL[0-9]*_LABEL", #formfields[i]#) EQ 1>
<cfset arrayAppend(entattval_label, "#formfields[i]#")>
</cfif>
</cfloop>
```

will make separate arrays for each subset of variables I need. But how do I make it print the contents of the variables, instead of their names?

```
<cfset #label_length# = arraylen(#entattval_label#)>
<cfloop from="1" to="#label_length#" index="i">
<cfoutput>#entattval_label[i]#</cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: I do something similar.  I would loop through your first collection to find how many sets you have.  Then I build a new query object and loop through my other values adding rows to the query for each item... then I reference the query object to display info.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but when using `cfset`, you do not need to wrap the variable names in `#`, nor as arguments to functions. `<cfset #formFields = listToArray(#form.fieldnames#, ",") >` should be written `<cfset formFields = listToArray(form.fieldnames, ",")>`. Same goes for the next 2 lines - none of them need `#`. Using `#` when it is not needed is a big pet peeve of mine.

Comment: Sorry, Scott Stroz, and thanks for the tip. I'm still new to Coldfusion and not yet clear on when to use # and when not to. It seems to error more if I leave them out from places than if I put them into places, so I just put them everywhere. I'll do better next time!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can reference a variable with a dynamic name using what's called array notation:

`foo.bar` can also be written as `foo['bar']` - even though it's a structure and not an array.

This means that you can inject any dynamic name into your reference that you like; and this also works for built in variable scopes like form, url, etc:

For example: `form['ent#i#att#j#val#k#_label']` where `i`, `j`, and `k` are the integers you need.

If you find that hard to read, you could also write it as:

```
form['ent' & i & 'att' & j & 'val' & k & '_label']
```

In these situations, if the form is being expanded on the client-side (e.g. with JavaScript) without  server involvement, I often find it's easiest to include a numeric hidden field (or in your case, maybe 3?) to indicate the ranges for i, j, and k.

Comment: Wow. That makes it a whole lot easier! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

(Too long and too much formatting for an easily-readable comment.)

Just for the record, you can significantly shorten your code by using `ReMatchNoCase()` instead of ReFind() if you're using CF8+ or Railo.

`ReMatchNoCase` (and `ReMatch` of course) looks for as many matches as possible. I created a form.fieldnames variable for demonstration but that's not even really needed

```
<cfset form.fieldnames = "ent1_label,ent2_label,notvalid,btnSelect,ent1att1_label,ent1att2_label,ent2att1_label,ent2att2_label,ent1att1val1_label,ent1att1val2_label,ent2att2val2_label">
<Cfset NamesArray = REMatchNoCase("ENT[0-9]*ATT[0-9]*VAL[0-9]*_LABEL",form.fieldnames)>
<cfoutput><cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(NamesArray)#" index="i">
    #NamesArray[i]#: #form[NamesArray[i]]#<br />
  </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```